# document.getElementById('url_input').value doesn't print the value

Tags: javascript

I was tring to get the value of text input with follow code:

```
var input = document.getElementById('url_input').value;
```

and

```
document.getElementById("send_url").onclick = function(){
  console.log(input);
}
```

this doesn't work, but if i change like this:

```
var input = document.getElementById('url_input');
document.getElementById("send_url").onclick = function(){
  console.log(input.value);
}
```

what's the different between this two? Why the first one is not working?

Comment: Please post your html.

Comment: Storing the value vs reading the value.

Comment: Post full html please, but seems that you are storing input value before setting the value in the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what's the different between this two?

In your first example, you *copy* the value into `input`:

```
var input = document.getElementById('url_input').value;
```

and then repeatedly re-log that value:

```
document.getElementById("send_url").onclick = function(){
  console.log(input);
}
```

Copying the value into `input` doesn't create any kind of ongoing link between `input` and the `HTMLInputElement`'s `value` property. It just copies the value of `value` *as of when that line of code runs* into `input`.

In your second example, you're getting the value from the `HTMLInputElement` each time:

```
var input = document.getElementById('url_input');
document.getElementById("send_url").onclick = function(){
  console.log(input.value);
}
```

On each click, you're asking the `HTMLInputElement` for its *current* state. Note that the value in `input` still doesn't change between clicks; it's a reference to the `url_input` element, which is an object, and that reference doesn't change in this code. It's the *state* of the object (the `HTMLInputElement`) that changes, and you're asking it for its current state each time.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you read the .value it is the value at that moment in time. It does not keep updating the variable when the property changes.

So when you do

```
var input = document.getElementById('url_input').value
```

If stores the value at that moment in time and that is the value that will be in the variable.